# Display the preview - independent of parent styles in a preview editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic wysiswyg editor

All works good, but the preview shows the bootstrap styles or any other parent styles
Rather I prefer to have it shown using an iframe to the styles are independent and not based on parent styles

I also want the js code to be improved to reflect the best jquery coding classess to use new jq classes like toggleClass etc.

```html
<html>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<head>
    <style>
    .stool {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index:999;
        
    }

    #html {
        display: none;
    }

    #w3review-preview {
        display: none;
    }

    textarea {
        outline: none;
    }

    
    </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container position-relative border">
        <div class="toolbar mt-3">
            <small class="bg-light stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2" id="preview">
                Preview
            </small>
            <small class="bg-light stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2" id="html">
                HTML
            </small>
        </div>
        
        <div class="editor">
            <textarea id="w3review" class="m-0 p-0 border-0"  style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; ">&lt;h3&gt;At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.&lt;/h3&gt;</textarea>
            <div id="w3review-preview" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".stool").click(function() {
        $(this).toggle(), $(this).siblings().toggle(), togglePreview()
    });
    let showPreview = !1;
    const w3Preview = $("#w3review-preview");

    function togglePreview() {
        showPreview ? (w3Preview.hide(), $(w3review).show()) : (w3Preview.html(w3review.value), w3Preview.show(), $(w3review).hide()), showPreview = !showPreview
    }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via iframe to accomplish a very basic wysiswyg preview editor

```html
<html>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<head>
    <style>
    .stool {
        cursor: pointer;
        user-select: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        z-index: 999;

    }

    #html {
        display: none;
    }

    #w3review-preview {
        display: none;
    }

    textarea {
        outline: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body class="p-3">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container position-relative border">
        <div class="toolbar mt-3">
            <small class="bg-light stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2" id="preview">
                Preview
            </small>
            <small class="bg-light stool position-absolute top-0 end-0 px-2" id="html">
                HTML
            </small>
        </div>

        <div class="editor">
            <textarea id="w3review" class="m-0 p-0 border-0" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;resize: none; ">&lt;h3&gt;At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.&lt;/h3&gt;</textarea>
                        
            <iframe src="javascript:void(0);" id="w3review-preview" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:75%;">

            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    let showPreview = !1;
    const w3Preview = $("#w3review-preview");
    
    $(".stool").click(function() {
        $(this).toggle();
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
        showPreview ? (w3Preview.hide(), $(w3review).show()) : 
        ($(w3Preview).contents().find('html').html(w3review.value),
        w3Preview.show(), 
        $(w3review).hide()), 
        showPreview = !showPreview
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```